# #elseif vs #elif (C/C++ preprocessor)

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

I have found that writing

```
#ifdef ...
#elseif defined(...)
#else
#endif
```

always results in using either the #ifdef or the #else condition, never the #elseif.  But substituting #elif causes it to work as expected based on what's defined.  What convoluted purpose, if any, is served by the existence of #elseif?  And if none, why doesn't the preprocessor complain?

Maybe this is why for years (decades, really), I've been using ugly #else/#endif blocks, since at least they're reliable!

Comment: If the thing after `#ifdef` is defined, you should see an "Invalid preprocessing directive" error. ([Example](http://ideone.com/FCPtSD))

Comment: `#elseif` is not part of the C++ language. Only `#elif` exists: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/conditional

Answer (score 18):

`#elseif` is not defined. The preprocessor doesn't complain because your `#ifdef` is false, and the directives within that `#ifdef` block are not parsed. To illustrate it, this code is valid:

```
#if 0
#random nonsense
#else
// This must be valid
#endif
```

Answer (score -1):

I just uncovered in IAR Embedded Workbench for MSP430, v7.11.1, which reports icc430 --version as "IAR C/C++ Compiler V7.11.1.983/W32 for MSP430",
that #elseif compiles without error, but does NOT evaluate the same as #elif.